# Short Session Lengths In Google Analytics for Android

Tags: android, session, google-analytics

I'm currently working on an app that uses Wifi Direct to connect a group of devices. While the group is connected, there is no internet connectivity, so they collect analytics hits to be sent once wifi direct is disabled. The hits are successfully sent, and I am able to view them in my dashboard. The session times, however, appear to be off. I have not had a session that has lasted more than a few seconds, despite hits registering for a 5 minute period. My average session length is 0 seconds. I have checked my session time out settings, and they are set to 30 minutes. Each time the app is opened, an explicit start session command is issued. I am using a static tracker that is created when the app is started.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening?

EDIT:
I found out what was happening. I was following the Google Analytics guide found here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/sessions
What this guide fails to mention is that the session control field needs to be changed after an event has been sent with it. Any string other than "start" or "end" will work, I chose "during".

Comment: you know you can answer your own question yes?